# Trouble printing out the max key/value pair in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working on trying to calculate the greatest increase/decrease in a change to profits/losses over time from a CSV.

The data set in csv is as follows (extract only):

Date,Profit/Losses

Jan-2010,867884

Feb-2010,984655

Mar-2010,322013

Apr-2010,-69417

So far, i've imported the csv file and added the items to a dictionary. Calculated total months, total profit/loss, calculated the change in profit/loss from month to month but now  need to find the greatest and smallest change in the month and have the code return both the month and the change figure.

The output when trying to print the greatest increase/decrease returns only the final month on the list and all change values (instead of just the biggest change value and it's corresponding month)

Here is the code. Would appreciate any perspective:

```
budget = {}
total_months = 0
total_pnl = 0
date = 0
pnl = 0
monthly_change = []
previous_pnl = 0
greatest_increase = ["Date",[0]]
greatest_decrease = ["Date",[100000000000000]]


with open(csvpath, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(csvreader)

for row in csvreader:
    date = 0
    pnl = 1
    budget[row[date]] = int(row[pnl])
    
for date, pnl in budget.items():
    total_months = total_months + 1
    total_pnl = total_pnl + pnl
    pnlchange = pnl - previous_pnl

if total_months > 1:
   monthly_change.append(pnlchange)

    previous_pnl = pnl

if (monthly_change > greatest_increase[1]):
    greatest_increase[1] = monthly_change
    greatest_increase[0] = row[0]

if (monthly_change < greatest_decrease[1]):
    greatest_decrease[1] = monthly_change
    greatest_decrease[0] = row[0]

 print(greatest_increase)
```

The primary problem is the final part of the code (the if statement). When I print 'greatest_increase' this currently returns the final value in the list rather than the highest value of change.

current output is:

[['Feb-2017', '671099'], [116771, -662642, -391430, 379920, 212354, 510239, -428211, -821271, 693918, 416278, -974163, 860159, -1115009, 1033048, 95318, -308093, 99052, -521393, 605450, 231727, -65187, -702716, 177975, -1065544, **1926159**, -917805, 898730, -334262, -246499, -64055, -1529236, 1497596, 304914, -635801, 398319, -183161, -37864, -253689, 403655, 94168, 306877, -83000, 210462, -2196167, 1465222, -956983, 1838447, -468003, -64602, 206242, -242155, -449079, 315198, 241099, 111540, 365942, -219310, -368665, 409837, 151210, -110244, -341938, -1212159, 683246, -70825, 335594, 417334, -272194, -236462, 657432, -211262, -128237, -1750387, 925441, 932089, -311434, 267252, -1876758, 1733696, 198551, -665765, 693229, -734926, 77242, 532869]]

What i am trying to get is the bold value being the highest value (along with the relevant month)

Apologies if this isn't clear, I'm still fairly new (3rd week learning!)

Comment: I recommend using Pandas for tabular data analysis.

Comment: monthly_change is a list possibly having multiple values which is going into greatest increase/decrease.

Comment: This question is reasonably good, but please show what you have tried and where it has failed or where you are stuck. The `Pandas` module is generally useful for this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've update the q to try and make it clearer. I'm trying to do the exercise without pandas for the moment  (though I know it would be much easier) before moving on to trying with Pandas next week (part of uni assignments).